# jQuery contains with a list of Guids

Tags: jquery, contains, custom-data-attribute

I have custom data-attributes on option-tags which contains a list of `Guid`s, like

```
<option data-show-for="64be38c4-1fcc-4f09-80ff-6d8075a2fcb1,b2457a92-e743-41f7-a448-a171bcfe92e1,2f02a194-4fff-417e-b776-f686f307c919">
```

If changing another value, I want to only show those elements, which contain the selected `Guid` in the listing of the data-attribute. Or, also possible, hiding those element which do not have the selected `Guid` in the listing.

How can this be achieved using `jQuery`?

**Update #1**

As of current answers do not solve my problem (or I am missing some important point), I want to clarify my problem.

I have a `<select id="hidemyoptions">` with several `<option>`s. Each `<option>` does have a data-attribute with the listing of `Guid`s, separated by comma.

Another `<select id="settheid">` sets an `Guid`-value. In the `hidemyoptions`-`<select>` I know want to:

1. Show only those `<option>`s which data-attribute contains the `Guid` set by `settheid` or
2. Hide those `<option>`s which data-attribute does not contain the `Guid` set by `settheid`

**Update #2**

Solution that is working for me:

```
$("#hidemyoptions option").not("[data-show-for*='" + selectedPlaceId + "']").hide();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use attribute selector for this.

```
var guid="64be38c4-1fcc-4f09-80ff-6d8075a2fcb1,b2457a92-e743-41f7-a448-a171bcfe92e1,2f02a194-4fff-417e-b776-f686f307c919"
$("option[data-show-for='"+guid +"']").prop("selected",true);
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/anoopjoship/16n051p8/3/)

**Edit as per requirement**

```
var guid = "2f02a194-4fff-417e-b776-f686f307c919";
$("option").hide();
$("option").filter(function() {
    return $(this).data("show-for").indexOf(guid) > -1;
}).show();
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/anoopjoship/16n051p8/7/)

Comment: Not solving my problem. See my updated question. Also tried https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/ with the `not`-jQuery selector.

Comment: See my edit (found solution on given answers myself). Would your one be faster?

Comment: Your one is better. I forgot about the * selector in attribute

Answer (score 1):

hide option that doesn't have the specified guid

```
$guid = '64be38c4-1fcc-4f09-80ff-6d8075a2fcb1';

$('option').not('option[data-show-for*="'+$guid+'"]').hide();
```

Comment: See my updated question. Maybe I'm on the wrong way, but this is not solving my problem.

Comment: updated my code is faster than your method because i am searching only the option elements that have the specific atribute ,you are searching all the dom elements